# What is the difference between GARCH and MGARCH model

Tags: time-series, heteroscedasticity, garch

I am struggling with the different GARCH-type models. Is there a difference between a GARCH and a MGARCH model?

Comment: http://public.econ.duke.edu/~boller/Papers/glossary_arch.pdf is a full glossary of GARCH models written by Dr. Bollerslev himself.  Be aware that there are multiple different types of MGARCH, M could stand for "Multivariate", "Multiplicative" or "Mixture".  If you want further help you should clarify exactly where it is your stuck with written formulas and/or an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Garch models are for *univariate* series. (ex : GARCH, EGARCH ...)

MGarch models = Multivariate Garch models: they are devoted to the joint modeling of *several* times series (ex : DCC, CCC models..)